# Question about my contract regarding purchasing own flights

Tags: email, reimbursement

very recently, I have just emailed my new company that I will be purchasing my own flight ticket and they gave me the go sign and the amount that I can claim for it which is about $1300, any extra cost will be topped up by me..

I have a question though, and not wanting to sound stupid/ country-bumpkin sort by re-emailing back to the HR (it is my first time working overseas too..). In my contract it is stated as `XXX will also pay for your working visa application, up to $1,300 CAD for one economy single airfare from Singapore to Vancouver`

Pertaining to that sentence - `one economy single airfare`, does that means only one-way ticket?
The reason I am asking this is because, I have found out that 'one-way' ticket are generally more expensive, eg. 1.5k and if I am using 'return' ticket, eg. from Singapore to Japan (maybe stay in Japan for 3-4 days), the depart from Japan to Vancouver, it will cost me about the same amount but I am not sure if I will be reimburse on that..

Any ideas? Or should I simply ask the HR?

Comment: You should simply ask HR.  They can clarify the contract better than we can :)

Comment: Company specific, voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

> Or should I simply ask the HR?

Thats the best and most prudent thing to do. Assuming your HR knows what they're doing, they will be able to explain the policy in detail to you.

What usually happens is that HR expects you to choose the best deal for the company, so if you fly back and forth, you would book with return and then get that back.

But again, the only way to know for sure (and the easy way) is to ask HR about it. Explaining and clarifiying policy is one of the things they're there for.